# ngrx share state between apps

Tags: angular, ngrx

#### Goal

I have two apps (A & B) where B is 80% a subset of A. A uses ngrx and B will need about 20% of the same state. I would like to share the relevant actions, effects, reducers, and selectors/projections between the apps by creating a new root state for B and placing the reducers that I want from A onto it.

#### Problem

The problem is that the selectors are specific to the root state or at least a feature state (ex: `createSelector<RootStateA, Tsomething>((store) => store.something)`). So I can't reuse them on different root states.

#### Question

Is there a way to have two stores in different apps that reference some of the same selectors?

**Update:** I came up with a solution that I posted below but I am open to other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly an additional meta-selector that can be reused? `createMetaSelector = <T>() => createSelector<T, Tsomething>((store) => store.something)); const createSelectorA = createMetaSelector<RootStateA>()`. Type safety has a price.

Comment: @estus Good suggestion and your right about the price of type safety :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think that I found a way. If I create an interface for each slice of state that I make RootState implement and I reference it in my selectors then it seems to work. Here is the basic approach:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string
}

interface UsersSlice {
  users: User[];
}

const selectUsers = (state: UsersSlice) => state.users;

interface RootState extends UsersSlice {
}

class MyComponent {
  private data: Observable<User[]>;
  constructor(private store: Store<RootState>) {
    this.data = store.select(selectUsers);
  }
}
```

Overall the approach doesn't add much boiler plate since you have to define RootState anyways. In this approach you just compose it out of "slice state". Then you can just reference the granular slice that you care about rather than the world.

It can explode a bit if you have a lot of selectors that cross into different slices of state. If you reference RootState then it isn't portable. You could make an interface that extended the slices of state that you wanted like the following:

```
interface Foo {
  id: number;
}
interface Bar {
  id: string;
}
interface FooBar {
  foo: Foo;
  bar: Bar;
}
interface FooSlice {
  foo: Foo;
}
interface BarSlice {
  bar: Bar;
}
const selectFoo = (state: FooSlice) => state.foo;
const selectBar = (state: BarSlice) => state.bar;
const selectFooBar = createSelector<FooBarSlice, Foo, Bar, FooBar>(
  selectFoo,
  selectBar,
  (foo: Foo, bar: Bar) => (<FooBar>{ foo, bar })
)
interface FooBarSlice extends FooSlice, BarSlice {}
interface RootSlice extends FooSlice, BarSlice, FooBarSlice {
  ...
}
```

So, at worst, you could end up with a number of interfaces equal to the number of all possible slice combinations.

A more reasonable alternative is to create ad-hoc intersections like this (`FooSlice & BarSlice`):

```
const selectFooBar = createSelector<FooSlice & BarSlice, Foo, Bar, FooBar>(
  selectFoo,
  selectBar,
  (foo: Foo, bar: Bar) => (<FooBar>{ foo, bar })
)
```

For state within a feature slice you will have to modify it as follows:

```
interface FeatureRoot extends FooSlice, BarSlice {}
const featureKey = 'feature';
interface FooState { 'feature': FooSlice; }
interface BarState { 'feature': BarSlice; }
type FeatureState = RootState & FooState & BarState;

const selectFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<FeatureRoot>(featureKey);
const selectFooState = createFeatureSelector<FooSlice>(featureKey);
const selectBarState = createFeatureSelector<BarSlice>(featureKey);

const selectFoo = createSelector(selectFooState, x => x.foo);
const selectBar = createSelector(selectBarState, x => x.bar);

class MyComponent {
  private foo: Observable<Foo>;
  private bar: Observable<Bar>;
  constructor(private store: Store<FeatureState>) {
    this.foo = store.select(selectFoo);
    this.bar = store.select(selectBar);
  }
}
```